# asp.net mvc parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to display a prompt message when he is redirceted from a special page, how can accomplish this?
Passing messsage as paramater is not so pretty.
a used a booling paramater to determinig situation to display message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not pass the boolean in `ViewData` (whether to display the message) based upon interrogating `Request.ServerVariables["http_referer"]` in your controller?

in controller

```
ViewData["DisplayMessage"] = 
    Request.ServerVariables["http_referer"] == "http://Special.com";
```

in view

```
<% if ((bool)ViewData["DisplayMessage"])){ %>
<div>YOUR MESSAGE</div>
<% } %>
```

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: So i need to define so many message in detination page for each source page, and if a new page being added i should change detination page.
that's not so good!